# Break out from Vim insert mode when pasting

Tags: security, vim

Can one put control characters into a text so that when I copy and paste it in Vim it exits insert mode and does something nasty in command mode?

Comment: Oops, I thought you wanted to do the opposite.

Comment: Well, I was hoping one can't do that, but I'm actually not sure ...

Comment: What keystrokes (or menu or mouse operations) do you use to paste and are you on Windows?

Comment: Added new tag to clear things up... that is, if I myself understood the author properly. :)

Comment: The 'paste' option can be used to avoid some dangers of this.  Check out `:help paste`

Comment: @Jon Carter, I do not see any difference when I toggle `'paste'`.  I tried in both terminal and GUI.  See my comment on @bundacia's answer.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I think Ingo Karkat's answer below is the best actual answer I could come up with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on the environment, and the Vim command used.

Graphical GVIM can differentiate pastes from typed keys, but in the terminal, this is not (generally) possible. That's why Vim has the `'paste'` and `'pastetoggle'` options, to tell Vim what is expected. Despite that, if the character stream contains a key like `<Esc>` that switches modes, Vim will do so.

Instead of *pushing* text into Vim, it is safer to *pull* with Vim's `p`ut command: `"*p`. There, special characters like `<Esc>` will be inserted literally into the buffer; Vim won't switch modes here. The only Vim command that interprets register contents as typed (and therefore is susceptible to mode switch commands) is `i_CTRL-R`. To avoid that, one should use any of the other command variants, e.g. `i_CTRL-R_CTRL-R`.

#### summary

Pull text into Vim instead of pushing it; if you avoid the `i_CTRL-R` command (or neuter it by remapping it), this is safe. Additionally, the `:registers` command allows you to inspect all contents before pasting.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer seems to be "yes". I was able to put the following in my clipboard:

`hello<Escape>:!date<CR>`

and when I pasted it into vim while in insert mode `hello` was typed and then the shell opened up and the `date` command was run.

Obviously if I can run the date command in the shell I can do much more nasty stuff.

To get that string in my paste buffer I opened vim and typed `hello<C-V><Esc>:!date<C-V><Enter>`. I then had to save that file, open it with Kate and copy the contents that way (copying from vim didn't preserve the control characters).

Comment: On Mac OS X, I find that MacVim (the GUI version) allows me to copy the special characters, and when I paste them in, they are simply added to the buffer.  I only get the unsafe behavior when pasting into vim running in a terminal window.

Comment: I was able to do the same, just typing it in Vim, copying in vim (with `0y$`), then pasting in insert mode (`<CTRL-R>"`).